# Limit cycles of the system

Tags: dynamical-systems, limit-cycles

$$\dot x=y+x[\mu-(x^2+y^2-1)^2]$$

$$\dot y=-x+y[\mu-(x^2+y^2-1)^2]$$

I used the polar coordinates substitution :

$$x=r\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$

and via the expressions :

$$r\dot r=x\dot x+y\dot y$$

$$\dot\theta=\frac{x\dot y−y\dot x}{r^2}$$

Using a polar coordinate substitution correctly for $x$ and $y$, one yields : :

$$\dot r=r(\mu-(r^2-1)^2)$$

$$\dot\theta=-1 $$

I found:
$$r=0, r=\pm\sqrt{1+\sqrt\mu} ,r=\pm\sqrt{1-\sqrt\mu} $$

Which one of these limit cycles is stable and which one is unstable and why?

Answer (score 1):

The first factor $r$ is always positive for $r>0$.

The second factor has value $μ−1$ at $r=0$. At each positive root it will switch sign, until after the upper root the term becomes negative.

This gives a stable cycle at the upper root. The lower root is either not real or results in an unstable cycle.